# Stylesheets in E-Mails when using extra sidekiq server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, premailer

we have the following server setup:

- Application Server
- Background Job Server (ActiveJob with Sidekiq)
- Database Server

The normal workflow would be:

1. User visits site and fills out register form
2. After submit a welcome email gets set to `deliver_later`
3. Sidekiq does the delivering.

Now we use [premailer-rails](https://github.com/fphilipe/premailer-rails) for styling our emails. The css file is located under `app/assets/stylesheets/emails/base.scss`. We reference it in the `mail.html.haml`-Layout with `stylesheet_link_tag 'emails/base'`. This works great in development and when previewing the mails.

But if we deploy everything and test it out on production we're getting the error:
`ActionView::Template::Error: The asset "emails/base.css" is not present in the asset pipeline`

It works very well when we're telling capistrano to precompile the assets also on the worker server. But this seems to be a little overhead.

Is this the only solution to fix the problem?
Does anyone have a similar setup and problem?

Regards,
spa

Answer (score 0):

By default, Rails assumes that you have your files pre-compiled in the production environment if you want to use live compiling (compile your assets during runtime) in production you must set the `config.assets.compile` to `true`.

**config/environments/production.rb**
...

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Comment: But then we would have live compiling for the normal website too. That's not what we want. So the only solution would be to compile the assets on the worker server too?